# Cross Domain User Tracking

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, user-tracking

We have several websites on different domains and I'd like to be able to track users' movements on these sites.

- Obviously cookies are not feasable, because they don't cross domain borders.
- I could look at a combination of IP address and User Agent, but there are some cases where that does not work.
- I don't want to use flash or other plugins.

Any ideas? Or am I doomed to rely on the IP/User_Agent combination?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can designate one domain or subdomain to tracking and have it serve a 1x1 pixel image which you include in all pages you would like to track. Serve a cookie with the image, look at the tracking domain's server logs, voilà.

Comment: That won't work. Internet Explorer default security settings won't allow pictures from other domains (or iframes) to set any cookies.

Comment: ... okay, revised: will work if I take http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323752/EN-US/ into account :)

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know that IE6 does this - I haven't used frames much recently. So you have to use the HTTP headers trick, or does setting cookies work when not using frames?

Comment: The problem that this is require extra work to be done. You have to include that in every page you need to track.

Comment: Well I don't understand how will it track user on cross domain. Obviously I cannot put 1x1 pixel on the cross domain site so how will you track user there?

Answer (score 7):

This solution requires no JavaScript, and works even if the user disables third-party cookies.

First, let's make sure the user agent is sending cookies:

`If getCookie("c") == null then setCookie("c", "anyValue")`

Then let the request finish (aka wait for next request)

Let's call our tracker cookie `uaid`.

If `GET` `http://child.com/any-page` and `getCookie("c") is not null` and `getCookie("uaid") is null`...

Redirect to `http://parent.com/give-me-a-uaid?returnTo=http://child.com/any-page`

On `http://parent.com/give-me-a-uaid`, check for cookie `uaid`

If not exists, create it and add it to response. If it exists, get its value.

Redirect to `http://child.com/any-page?uaid=valueOfParentsUAIDCookie`

Child.com sets cookie `uaid` with `valueOfParentsUAIDCookie`

Redirect to `http://child.com/any-page`

And of course, you are **validating input**, and **white-listing your redirect URLs** :)

Flows:

[image: Scenario A]

[image: Scenario B]

[image: Scenario C]

Answer (score 3):

This question is closely related to the Question [Accessing Domain Cookies within an iFrame on Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98127/accessing-domain-cookies-within-an-iframe-on-internet-explorer).

For Internet Explorer I need to take P3P Policies into account and set an [additional P3P HTTP-Header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323752/EN-US/) to allow images to set cookies across domain borders. Then I can use simon's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same concept used in Google Analytics. Injecting javascript in the pages you want to track.

Comment: I could, but how would that help me to track users across domain borders?

Comment: There are different types of tracking.
Google Analytics will let you look back at a history of your many visitors behaviour, even crossing domains. Another type of tracking such as PHP session tracking is used to control what content is served to a single visitor.

Comment: google analytics does exacly what simon said, and it injects an 1x1 pixle image, this is how it can track across multiple domains, and it does this injection by JS

Answer (score 0):

You do not give any context to your situation -just the basic problem.  So it is difficult to give an answer that clearly fits.  However, here are some techniques/mechanisms for passing information from one page to another, regardless of what domain is involved.

- include hyperlink to a 1x1 pixel transparent gif image (sometimes called a "beacon")
- rely on referrer information in HTTP request headers to identify page hyperlink is on
- include extra parameters in hyperlinks to other site - assuming you run both sites
- buy services of a company like [Akamai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) to do user tracking for you
- possibly use cross domain cookie mechanism in the future if standard is ever approved

Which techniques really come down to whether you can place software on all of the sites (servers) that the user will visit where you have interest - or you cannot place your software on all of them.