# php logging with cookie, Internet Explorer 9

Tags: php, cookies

Why cookies does not work works in IE9, in other browsers it works?

In logging in i use a code

```
$expires = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
$time = time() + $expires;
setcookie ("username", $user, $time, "/");
setcookie ("password", $pass , $time, "/");
```

And in logging out i use code

```
$expires = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
$time = time() - $expires;
setcookie ("username", "", $time, "/");
setcookie ("password", "" , $time, "/");
```

In checking a logged user i use

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
    $result = mysql_query ( "select * from users where user=$_COOKIE['username'] and passwd=$_COOKIE['password']" );
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
        return $row;
    }
    return array();
}
```

How to solve that logging works in all browsers?
Thank you for hints

Regards

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it will helps you:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1211868/718829

Comment: Where to put the header("p2p:...");?? setcookie ("username", $user, $time, "/"); header("p2p:..."); or header("p2p:...");setcookie ("username", $user, $time, "/");??

Comment: header("p2p:..."); goes first in your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in all major browsers, specially IE

To save cookie:

```
setcookie('username', trim($username), time() + 6000000, '/');
setcookie('password', trim($password), time() + 6000000, '/');
```

To remove it:

```
setcookie('username', '', 0);
setcookie('password', '', 0);
unset($_COOKIE['username']);
unset($_COOKIE['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies do not write the password and user name. It's not safe.

Comment: I know, it's not safe. I'm interested, how to write correctly the code, that logging remembering cookies works well in all browsers.